# Is "have gone" identical to "have been" in some cases, such as being used to describe some status?

Tags: meaning, present-perfect, been-vs-gone

recently, SO pushed this [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters/?cb=1) everywhere, which says (expression_1)

> These options have `gone` untouched for a long time

it seems that this expression could be rewritten as (expression_2)

> These options have `been` untouched for a long time

assume expression_1 is identical to expression_2 in this case (of cause, this identity needs some double check), is 
"have gone" identical to "have been" in any other this kind of cases, where they are being used to describe some status?

Answer (score 2):

Ref: Cambridge

**gone**
verb UK ​  /ɡɒn/ US ​  /ɡɑːn/
​past participle of go
gone

**been**
verb UK ​  /biːn/ /bɪn/ US ​  /biːn/ /bɪn/
**used as the past participle of "go" when the action referred to is finished:**
We use have before -ed forms to make the present perfect and past perfect. …
Therefore I would conclude that "have gone" is identical to "have been"

Answer (score 0):

> X goes untouched for Y.

The use of *go* implies X is active, being used, or relevant in some sort of way.

> X is untouched for Y.

This simply says X hasn't been touched for duration Y.

If the options are something that still matters now and needs updating, *go* is going to imply more importance/urgency than *be*.